# Origin Point Wrong in AIR 15 Mobile App - Flashbuilder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, adobe, flash-builder

I am using Flashbuilder 4.7 to create a mobile AIR app (using AIR 15) and the origin for y is about 1/3 of the way down the screen. I have written a simple app to replicate this. Here is the entirety of the code:

```
package{
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TestApp extends Sprite{
    static public var appHeight:Number;
    static public var appWidth:Number;

    static protected var instance:TestApp;

    public function TestApp(){
        super();

        appHeight   = stage.fullScreenHeight;
        appWidth    = stage.fullScreenWidth;

        instance    = this;

        this.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000FF);
        this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
}
```

I am getting this output (also occurs on devices): 
[image: Blue Square at 0, 0 is down the screen instead of at the top left.]

I have a Flex/AIR app that uses AIR 15 and the latest Apache Flex and has no issues, however I wanted to get away from Flex and create a strictly AS3/AIR app. I have attempted deleting and recreating the app with no success. Can anyone tell me where or how I would adjust the origin point back to the top left consistently throughout all devices and screensizes?

I have searched Google and StackOverflow without any luck at finding anything related to this, so if this is a duplicate, please point me to the original and I will either clarify or delete this.

In case it would help, my app.xml file follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15.0">

<!-- Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File Template.

Specifies parameters for identifying, installing, and launching AIR applications.

xmlns - The Adobe AIR namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5
        The last segment of the namespace specifies the version 
        of the AIR runtime required for this application to run.

minimumPatchLevel - The minimum patch level of the AIR runtime required to run 
        the application. Optional.
-->

<!-- A universally unique application identifier. Must be unique across all AIR applications.
Using a reverse DNS-style name as the id is recommended. (Eg. com.example.ExampleApplication.) Required. -->
<id>TestApp</id>

<!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
<filename>TestApp</filename>

<!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. 
May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
<name>TestApp</name>

<!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. 
Values can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value.
An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
<versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>

<!-- A string value (such as "v1", "2.5", or "Alpha 1") that represents the version of the application, as it should be shown to users. Optional. -->
<!-- <versionLabel></versionLabel> -->

<!-- Description, displayed in the AIR application installer.
May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
<!-- <description></description> -->

<!-- Copyright information. Optional -->
<!-- <copyright></copyright> -->

<!-- Publisher ID. Used if you're updating an application created prior to 1.5.3 -->
<!-- <publisherID></publisherID> -->

<!-- Settings for the application's initial window. Required. -->
<initialWindow>
    <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
    <!-- Note: In Flash Builder, the SWF reference is set automatically. -->
    <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>

    <!-- The title of the main window. Optional. -->
    <!-- <title></title> -->

    <!-- The type of system chrome to use (either "standard" or "none"). Optional. Default standard. -->
    <!-- <systemChrome></systemChrome> -->

    <!-- Whether the window is transparent. Only applicable when systemChrome is none. Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <transparent></transparent> -->

    <!-- Whether the window is initially visible. Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <visible></visible> -->

    <!-- Whether the user can minimize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
    <!-- <minimizable></minimizable> -->

    <!-- Whether the user can maximize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
    <!-- <maximizable></maximizable> -->

    <!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
    <!-- <resizable></resizable> -->

    <!-- The window's initial width in pixels. Optional. -->
    <!-- <width></width> -->

    <!-- The window's initial height in pixels. Optional. -->
    <!-- <height></height> -->

    <!-- The window's initial x position. Optional. -->
    <!-- <x></x> -->

    <!-- The window's initial y position. Optional. -->
    <!-- <y></y> -->

    <!-- The window's minimum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "400 200". Optional. -->
    <!-- <minSize></minSize> -->

    <!-- The window's initial maximum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "1600 1200". Optional. -->
    <!-- <maxSize></maxSize> -->

    <!-- The aspect ratio of the app ("portrait" or "landscape" or "any"). Optional. Mobile only. Default is the natural orientation of the device -->

    <!-- <aspectRatio></aspectRatio> -->

    <!-- Whether the app will begin auto-orienting on launch. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

    <!-- <autoOrients></autoOrients> -->

    <!-- Whether the app launches in full screen. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

    <!-- <fullScreen></fullScreen> -->

    <!-- The render mode for the app (either auto, cpu, gpu, or direct). Optional. Default auto -->

    <!-- <renderMode></renderMode> -->

    <!-- Whether the default direct mode rendering context allocates storage for depth and stencil buffers.  Optional.  Default false. -->
    <!-- <depthAndStencil></depthAndStencil> -->

    <!-- Whether or not to pan when a soft keyboard is raised or lowered (either "pan" or "none").  Optional.  Defaults "pan." -->
    <!-- <softKeyboardBehavior></softKeyboardBehavior> -->

    <!-- Display Resolution for the app (either "standard" or "high"). Optional, OSX-only. Default "standard" -->
    <!-- <requestedDisplayResolution></requestedDisplayResolution> -->
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <visible>true</visible>
</initialWindow>

<!-- We recommend omitting the supportedProfiles element, -->
<!-- which in turn permits your application to be deployed to all -->
<!-- devices supported by AIR. If you wish to restrict deployment -->
<!-- (i.e., to only mobile devices) then add this element and list -->
<!-- only the profiles which your application does support. -->
<!-- <supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice extendedMobileDevice</supportedProfiles> -->

<!-- Languages supported by application -->
<!-- Only these languages can be specified -->
<!-- <supportedLanguages>en de cs es fr it ja ko nl pl pt ru sv tr zh</supportedLanguages> -->

<!-- The subpath of the standard default installation location to use. Optional. -->
<!-- <installFolder></installFolder> -->

<!-- The subpath of the Programs menu to use. (Ignored on operating systems without a Programs menu.) Optional. -->
<!-- <programMenuFolder></programMenuFolder> -->

<!-- The icon the system uses for the application. For at least one resolution,
specify the path to a PNG file included in the AIR package. Optional. -->
<!-- <icon>
    <image16x16></image16x16>
    <image29x29></image29x29>
    <image32x32></image32x32>
    <image36x36></image36x36>
    <image40x40></image40x40>
    <image44x44></image44x44>
    <image48x48></image48x48>
    <image50x50></image50x50>
    <image57x57></image57x57>
    <image58x58></image58x58>
    <image60x60></image60x60>
    <image66x66></image66x66>
    <image72x72></image72x72>
    <image75x75></image75x75>
    <image76x76></image76x76>
    <image80x80></image80x80>
    <image87x87></image87x87>
    <image96x96></image96x96>
    <image100x100></image100x100>
    <image114x114></image114x114>
    <image120x120></image120x120>
    <image128x128></image128x128>
    <image144x144></image144x144>
    <image152x152></image152x152>
    <image180x180></image180x180>
    <image192x192></image192x192>
    <image512x512></image512x512>
    <image732x412></image732x412>
    <image1024x1024></image1024x1024>
</icon> -->

<!-- Whether the application handles the update when a user double-clicks an update version
of the AIR file (true), or the default AIR application installer handles the update (false).
Optional. Default false. -->
<!-- <customUpdateUI></customUpdateUI> -->

<!-- Whether the application can be launched when the user clicks a link in a web browser.
Optional. Default false. -->
<!-- <allowBrowserInvocation></allowBrowserInvocation> -->

<!-- Listing of file types for which the application can register. Optional. -->
<!-- <fileTypes> -->

    <!-- Defines one file type. Optional. -->
    <!-- <fileType> -->

        <!-- The name that the system displays for the registered file type. Required. -->
        <!-- <name></name> -->

        <!-- The extension to register. Required. -->
        <!-- <extension></extension> -->

        <!-- The description of the file type. Optional. -->
        <!-- <description></description> -->

        <!-- The MIME content type. -->
        <!-- <contentType></contentType> -->

        <!-- The icon to display for the file type. Optional. -->
        <!-- <icon>
            <image16x16></image16x16>
            <image32x32></image32x32>
            <image48x48></image48x48>
            <image128x128></image128x128>
        </icon> -->

    <!-- </fileType> -->
<!-- </fileTypes> -->

<!-- iOS specific capabilities -->
<!-- <iPhone> -->
    <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Info.plist -->
    <!-- <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
            <string>YES</string>
        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions> -->
    <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Entitlements.plist -->
    <!-- <Entitlements>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
            <array>
                <string></string>
                <string></string>
            </array>
        ]]>
    </Entitlements> -->
<!-- Display Resolution for the app (either "standard" or "high"). Optional. Default "standard" -->
<!-- <requestedDisplayResolution></requestedDisplayResolution> -->
<!-- Forcing Render Mode CPU for the devices mentioned. Optional  -->
<!-- <forceCPURenderModeForDevices></forceCPURenderModeForDevices> -->
<!-- File containing line separated list of external swf paths. These swfs won't be 
packaged inside the application and corresponding stripped swfs will be output in 
externalStrippedSwfs folder. -->
<!-- <externalSwfs></externalSwfs> -->
<!-- </iPhone> -->

<!-- Specify Android specific tags that get passed to AndroidManifest.xml file. -->
<!--<android> -->
<!--    <manifestAdditions>
    <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
            <application android:enabled="true">
                <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    ]]>
    </manifestAdditions> -->
    <!-- Color depth for the app (either "32bit" or "16bit"). Optional. Default 16bit before namespace 3.0, 32bit after -->
    <!-- <colorDepth></colorDepth> -->
    <!-- Indicates if the app contains video or not. Necessary for ordering of video planes with graphics plane, especially in Jellybean - if you app does video this must be set to true - valid values are true or false -->
    <!-- <containsVideo></containsVideo> -->
<!-- </android> -->
<!-- End of the schema for adding the android specific tags in AndroidManifest.xml file -->

<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <!--See the Adobe AIR documentation for more information about setting Google Android permissions-->
            <!--Removing the permission android.permission.INTERNET will have the side effect
                of preventing you from debugging your application on your device-->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>-->
            <!--The DISABLE_KEYGUARD and WAKE_LOCK permissions should be toggled together
                in order to access AIR's SystemIdleMode APIs-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>-->
            <!--The ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions should be toggled
                together in order to use AIR's NetworkInfo APIs-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>-->
        </manifest>

    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
</application>
```

Comment: You mean:
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; 
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
?  You need these.

Comment: You are a life-saver! I put these in at the top and it fixed it perfectly. I have no clue why it didn't default like this in the first place, though. 

Please submit this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need to declare these for apps:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; 
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Comment: I still say it makes no sense that you should have to do this, but it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: It's because you need other settings for desktop.  It's for the browser.  Desktop, and soon mobile, can stretch vector perfectly.